# PHP, MySQL, storing filename in a field

Tags: php, mysql

i was wondering what the best way to store a file name in a field.  i dont mind if the extension is chopped off or not.. so far i have

```
$fname = $_FILES["name"];

mysql_connect('myssdfebhost.com',$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "INSERT INTO uploadedfiles (filename) VALUES ('$fname')";
mysql_query($query);
```

but it doesnt put it in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things to note :

- I don't think you can use `$_FILES["name"]`:

  - instead, you should use `$_FILES['NAME OF YOUR INPUT FIELD']["name"]`
- You should escape `$fname` with [**`mysql_real_escape_string()`**](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), to avoid [SQL injections](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/SQL_injection).
- The uploaded file is uploaded to a temporary directory ; if you do not move it to a non-temporary location, it will automatically be deleted.

  - See the [**`move_uploaded_file()`**](https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file) function, about that, if you want to keep the file.

It could be interesting for you to use the following portion of code :

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

This will show you what's in the `$_FILES` array, so you know what you can use -- typically, you'll see the structure of that array, including the key that correspond to the **`name`** attribute of the `<input type="file" ... />` of your form.

About that `$_FILES` variable, btw, you should take a look at the following section of the manual : [**POST method uploads**][4].

Comment: thanks, can you elaborate on the mysql_real_escape_string() and what escaping actually does

Comment: @Shawn : basically, it ensures that special characters are escaped properly when sent to the SQL server, so they don't have their special meaning anymore -- I've edited my answer to provide a link to the relevant wikipedia article, where you can find more informations about SQL injections :-)